# Traversing a C++ tuple in an order defined at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, boost-tuples

It's possible to iterate over a boost or std tuple, but can I iterate in an order determined at runtime, while still retaining type information?

Suppose my tuple was filled with objects of type `Foo`:

```
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template <typename ...> void bar(); // Definition omitted.

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Foo {
  void doit() { bar<Ts...>(); }
  int rank;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto tup = make_tuple(Foo<int,double>(),
                        Foo<bool,char,float>());
  get<0>(tup).rank = 2;
  get<1>(tup).rank = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to traverse the list of `Foo` types, calling their `doit` methods, but in an arbitrary order defined by, say, the value of the `rank` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement some type erasure in order to make this happen. Something along the lines of

```
template <typename ...> void bar(); // Definition omitted.

struct FooBase {
    virtual void doit() = 0;
    int rank;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Foo : public FooBase {
  void doit() { bar<Ts...>(); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto tup = make_tuple(Foo<int,double>(),
                        Foo<bool,char,float>());
  get<0>(tup).rank = 2;
  get<1>(tup).rank = 1;
  std::vector<FooBase*> bases;
  // fill bases
  // sort
  // call
  return 0;
}
```

There are other mechanisms you can apply which are functional, for example, and do not require modifying Foo, but they all boil down to the same principle- type erasure. I merely provided the simplest implementation of that erasure.

Comment: Thankyou. I'm not immediately clear on how the "call" phase would work: after I sort `bases`, I have a `vector` of `(FooBase *)` but I need the full type to call `doit()`, no? I also have humble concerns about the portability of virtual functions, and would be very interested in the functional approach you mention.

Comment: @user643722: `virtual` functions are completely and totally portable, *vastly* more so than the template machinery powering `bar`. You need the full type to call `doit()`, but that type is "erased" by the virtual function and then known again in the actual `doit()` body.

Comment: Thanks again. I can make a vector of `(FooBase*)`, I expect `bases.push_back((FooBase*)&get<0>(tup));` would be a start. But, how can I call the `doit()` method once the ordering of `bases` has been altered: I don't know the type of each `(FooBase *)` pointer.

Comment: @user643722: Because it's a `virtual` method? The whole reason this works is because *you don't have to know* the derived type. It is abstracted at run-time.

Comment: If I make a call like `bases[0].doit();`, I get: `error: request for member 'doit' in` ... `which is of non-class type 'FooBase*'`

Comment: @user643722: Because `FooBase*` is a pointer, so you use `bases[0]->doit();`.

Comment: Oops, of course it is, sorry. I was so convinced that it wouldn't work; but it does. I clearly need to revise my knowledge of virtual methods. (Too much time with Haskell lately.) I will still seek a functional solution.